WordPress theme.json: Why doesn't "contentSize" work
On the WordPress 6.5.2 version, in the theme.json file, I have the following code
{
  "version": 2,
  "settings": {
    "layout": {
      "contentSize": "800px"
    }
  }
}

But it doesn’t work if editing any Post or opening Site Editor
Post Editing

Site Editor


I have found the solution, I should enable "Inner blocks use content width"
Screenshot 1 - https://ibb.co/qFBsxQf
Screenshot 2 - https://ibb.co/LRkdFmz
